# (Raspberry Pi 3B+) template string on node.js v8 not working

Tags: javascript, node.js, raspberry-pi3, raspbian

I want to let a discord bot run on a Raspberry 3B+. I already got the bot, it just has some issues. It even works pretty fine, but the template string, that allows to put parameters into strings doesn't work. I've heard that this feature is available from node.js v4 or better, but my node.js version  already is v8.11.1.

This is an example that works on windows, but not on Raspbian:

```
message.channel.send(`Oh ${message.author}, cuddles noone :/\nThat's... interesting...`);
```

it used to be a template string, but even the code highlighting won't see ` as a string-starting or -ending character

So in general: I want to type this into the code:

```
`${message.author} executed this command`
```

so the output will be

```
@Dipper executed this command
```

But the program doesn't recognite the backtick as a string starter.
I just got this raspberry for the bot, so my PC won't run 24/7.I have no idea what infos I may send too, also I set up everything fine, except this problem at the moment.

The error I get at the moment is:

```
/home/pi/Desktop/MelloBot/commands/pat.js:72
help: `<usermention> / Your daily dose of pat`
                     ^

SyntaxError: Invalid regular expression: missing /
at createScript (vm.js:80:10)
at Object.runInThisContext (vm.js:139:10)
at Module._compile (module.js:616:28)
at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:663:10)
at Module.load (module.js:565:32)
at tryModuleLoad (module.js:505:12)
at Function.Module._load (module.js:497:3)
at Module.require (module.js:596:17)
at reloadParent (/home/pi/Desktop/MelloBot/node_modules/require- 
reload/reload.js:29:23)
at reload (/home/pi/Desktop/MelloBot/node_modules/require- 
reload/reload.js:59:12)
```

The string there, as you can see is surrounded by ``
I made the bot with node.js on windows and copied it onto the rasp

Comment: What error message are you getting?

Comment: I added that part

Comment: Regular expression?! Please post a [mcve] of the code that produces the problem. Sounds more like a syntax mistake somewhere else (e.g. mismatched delimiters), only surfacing in that particular line.

Comment: I don't think this has anything to do with Raspian/the platform in general. You may remove the processor info from your question, that's hardly relevant. And can you assert that the *exact same code* works on Windows? What node.js version are you using there?

Comment: Bergi, the node version on Windows is 11.9.0, but theversion on the rasp is 8.11.1.
With "apt list nodejs -a" I checked available versions, but 8.11.1 was the newest in the list